# What does the hasSpeed() in android location?

Tags: android

I tried to understand the effect of hasSpeed() function in android(Locatio), but i still stuck at this point ,anyone clarify my doubt ?

Answer (score 0):

Simply put, it's the physically moving speed of the location provider.  For example, this can be used to [calculate the movement speed of a device](http://mycodingworld1.blogspot.com/2015/12/calculate-speed-from-gps-location.html) using the GPS.  You can read more on the official docs for [Location Strategies](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html).